# Weird &nbsp; appearing for no reason

Tags: html-entities

I've just launched my new site, and in going though it in multiple browsers to see how it performs, I've noticed something weird.

---

[image]

---

Can you see the gap after the word 'but'? By my reasoning, the word 'was' on the following line should be next to it, as there is plenty of space for it - but as you can see, it isn't.

Although this screenshot is from Firefox (10), I'm getting the same thing in Chrome (17) and Internet Explorer (9).

Using Firebug to inspect the element, it is showing a `&nbsp;` between the 'was' and 'disappointed' (which would explain why it isn't on the line above) - but upon viewing the source, no such `&nbsp;` exists.

This is leading me to suggest that the browser is inserting them - but I have no idea why.

Anyway, the page in question is http://limeblast.co.uk/2012/02/currently-playing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used wget to download the page directly to a file and I noticed that the space between was and 'disappointed' and all other spaces that you see as

```
&nbsp;
```

are encoded with two bytes, C2 A0 hex, while the other spaces are encoded with one byte, 20hex.
Hope this helps.

Off-topic, I would also recommend justifying the text.

Comment: This is weird - I have no idea how, but I guess I must have been using two different types of space - no doubt from copy/pasting content from somewhere else... - or maybe something to do with the 'after the deadline' thing I was using as part of jetpack... Anyway, I've replaced all the 'weird' spaces with 'real' spaces, and it is working as intended again.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into your colorbox implementation.  It isn't working properly, and it's causing other issues on the page.  I don't think it's necessarily related to what you're describing, but fix it, and you'll get your colorbox effect that you're after.

Comment: Can you let me know what is wrong with my colorbox implementation? So far as I can tell, it is working as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and tried a few things with your code, best solution I would recommend is to force your

to be justified, right now your text is left aligned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't want justified text (makes it harder to read).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with text coming from the WP tinymce editor. This here solved it for me:

```
function b09_remove_forced_spaces($content) {
    $string = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8');
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $string);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter("the_content", "b09_remove_forced_spaces", 9);
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801444/586823