# replace &nbsp; characters that are hidden in text

Tags: php, regex, unicode

How to remove `&nbsp;` (that are hidden) and SPACES in below text but

- hold UNICODE characters
- hold `<br>` tag

i tested:

- i used `trim($string)` => NOT WORKED
- i used `str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $string)` => NOT WORKED
- i used some regex => NOT WORKED

  ```
              <br>تاريخ ورود: یکشنبه ۲۳ بهمن ماه ۱۳۹۰
  ```

UPDATE: [image: Image of hidden]
Thanks

Comment: Use \s in your regex to match a space

Comment: i did it, but just spaces between words changed. &nbsp; are exist yet

Comment: Sorry, can you post the html up as text so I can copy it

Comment: Nothing on this entire page works for me...

Comment: Final solution in above question worked for me. i.e.    $string = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');
            $string = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $string);

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This solution will work, I tested it:

```
$string = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8');
$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $string);
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
```

Comment: O. My. God. Finally the solution, after hours of searching!! Thank you so much. I had issues with &nbsp; preventing my tinymce text  to break nicely, so I replaced all of them with a real space: 
`function b09_remove_forced_spaces($content) {
    $string = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8');
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $string);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter("the_content", "b09_remove_forced_spaces", 9);`

(bad thing that stackoverflow doesn't allow for code blocks in comments

Answer (score 39):

Not tested, but if you use something like:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s/",'',$string);
```

That should remove all spaces.

**UPDATE**

To remove all spaces and `&nbsp;` references, use something like:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s|&nbsp;/",'',$string);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try this:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string);

$string = preg_replace("/\s/",'',$string);

echo $string;
```

Forgot to say, reconvert the html entities so add this after the replacement:

```
htmlentities($string);
```

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can test it myself

Comment: I am unable to test it but try `preg_replace("/(\s)|(\&nbsp\;)/",'',$string);`

Comment: Okay, I am looking into it further

Comment: Can you post up some of the html to your question, and then I can work with that

Comment: thanks worked with this:
$string = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');

Comment: A different solution from [@BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515394/620410) worked for me.

Comment: `htmlentities` instead of html_entities at the end of answer. PHP is confusing in this regards - some functions have underscore between the words, some do not.

Comment: Tested, and does remove `&nbsp;` in phpExcel export method: `->setCellValue('L'.$i, preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}|&nbsp;/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $row['plaintiff']))`

Answer (score 5):

All solutions above kind of work, until one starts to work with German language where there are such letters:

```
ä &auml;
```

and othere simial ones.
I use the following code:

```
$string = preg_replace ( "!\s++!u", ' ', $string );
```

More details here: [PCRE(3) Library Functions Manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Comment: A quantifier at the end of a pattern becomes de facto possessive: since it isn't followed by a subpattern, backtracking will never occur on it. So `!\s+!u` is shorter, as efficient and does the same.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```html
preg_replace("/&nbsp;/",'',$string)
```