# preg_match works in builder, but not in script

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, screen-scraping

I have am creating a regex with
https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match

the code looks like:

```
$input_line = 'Sector(s) : Basic Materials Industry : Gold Full-time employees :  ';
preg_match('/Industry : (.*) Full-time employees :/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

in the online tool the result is as expected, which is "Gold".

However in my code this is not happening:

```
echo preg_match('/Industry : (.*) Full-time employees :/', $arr[5], $industry_arr);
```

returns 0.

The array $arr looks like this:

`Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => Sector(s) : Basic Materials Industry : Gold Full-time employees :  [6] => [7] => )`

In the developer tool my array looks like this though, and I get confused:

```
(
    [0] =&gt; 
    [1] =&gt; 
    [2] =&gt; 
    [3] =&gt; 
    [4] =&gt; 
    [5] =&gt; Sector(s) :&nbsp;Basic Materials 
Industry :&nbsp;Gold 
Full-time employees :\&nbsp; 
    [6] =&gt; 
    [7] =&gt; 
)
```

if I do echo $arr[5] i get the following:

```
Sector(s) : Basic Materials Industry : Gold Full-time employees :
```

I am wondering whether the non breaking space is causing issues here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try doing `echo $arr[5]`, and then include this in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lays in the &nbsp character.

Unfortunately the solution posted here does not work
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

What worked was:

```
  $string = htmlentities($arr[5], null, 'utf-8');
  $clean_string = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $string);
  $clean_string = html_entity_decode($clean_string);
```

I found it here:
[replace &nbsp; characters that are hidden in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870974/replace-nbsp-characters-that-are-hidden-in-text)

This cleaned the string to a "normal" string and the running a regex worked as expected.